# Flutter how to know there is a new post or not?

Tags: http, flutter

I'm working on a project, I get posts from the server How can I know there is a new post on the server to fetch or not? like Facebook that shows "new" if there is new posts. This should handle from the server-side or Flutter?

Comment: You have to use real-time database like firebase or implement socket connection to your server and listen for new data

Comment: Can you add the logic you used to receive that same request? And if not I do think that it is handled on server side, as the new posts will only be sent to the server to the browser when the user refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can poll the server every couple minutes, this you can handle in your app alone without changes on the server. This should be pretty simple and straight forward with some timer.

Or you implement push notification so that the server can tell you that there are new posts, this requires work on server and app and also is more work.